# AngularJS - run some DOM-updating javascript after $scope has been applied?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to do something in the DOM after making changes to a $scope variable, but I'm having some trouble.

Here is the code:

```
$scope.addThingToDOM = function() {
    $scope.elementList.push({value: "new thing"});
    var elementListDiv = document.getElementById("element-list");
    elementListDiv.scrollTop = elementListDiv.scrollHeight;
};
```

(elementListDiv contains the elements in $scope.elementList, and I'm trying to automatically scroll down when a new element is added. addThingToDom gets called from an ng-click on a button.)

Ideally, elementListDiv would have parity with $scope.elementList after the change to $scope.elementList is made, but that does not seem to be the case. The DOM isn't updated by the time I want to mess with it. It actually works when I call $scope.$apply() after I update the elementList, but Angular gives me errors if I do that.

Is there a way to call some javascript AFTER the current $scope changes have been applied?

Answer (score 0):

Don't perform DOM manipulation in the controllers. When you avoid doing DOM manipulation in your controllers and restrict it to directives - changes to the scope are *automatically* detected and handled for you by Angular through the digest cycle.

The fact doing a `$scope.$apply()` works is exactly because it schedules a digest cycle. You can either use a "safer" apply by putting the code inside a `$timeout` which will only schedule a digest if it needs to (eliminating the errors) or you can write idiomatic Angular and put it in a directive.

I strongly encourage you to take the second approach, digests in directive are a lot simpler and there are excellenet tutorials about directives online (I recommend the one on egghead.io).

Answer (score 0):

You could probably make use of [$evalAsync](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync) however, direct interaction with the DOM should probably be turfed off to a directive.

```
$scope.addThingToDOM = function() {
    $scope.elementList.push({value: "new thing"});
    $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
        var elementListDiv = document.getElementById("element-list");
        elementListDiv.scrollTop = elementListDiv.scrollHeight;
    });
};
```